# How to read filenames with spaces in Unix array

Tags: unix, ksh

I have the following line:

```
for FILE in $(find "${DIR}" -type f -mtime +14 -level 0)
```

The trouble is if I have a file named "New Document.txt", on the first pass the value of $FILE will be "New" and on the second it will be "Document". How do I get it to keep filenames together?

I am running this in a windows environment, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop use the while loop

```
find "${DIR}" -type f -mtime +14 -level 0 |while read FILE
do
  ls -l  "${FILE}"
done
```

good luck